# Trying to get my current PHP programs to access the DB created by MyPhpAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, workbench

I have a DB that I created using MYSQL workbench.  I was later given access to MyphpAdmin.  I was not able to connect to the DB created by Workbench while using MyPhpAdmin.

I then created the same DB using MyPhpAdmin, but now my code, (PHP) cannot locate the DB created by MyPhpAdmin.

I would rather use the DB created by MyPhpAdmin, so what do I need to do to connect to the MyPhpAdmin DB.  They are both located on the same server and I am using XAMPP/Apache

Thanks.
Don "Ho"

Answer (score 0):

You can use PDO for that :

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb;port=3306', 'user', 'pass');
```

and then use that to make requests :

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND status=?');
$stmt->execute([$email, $status]);
$user = $stmt->fetch();
```

for fetching multiple rows :

```
$stmt  = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute([$search]);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

and if there is no parameter you can just use query :

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT name FROM users');
```

check out the documentation for pdo, there is a lot more functions, like rowCount and so on

Comment: Looks like you are telling me that the MyPhpAdmin db is access thru port :3306?  That is the db I am looking to connect.  I currently am using mysqli... to access the db.

Comment: Well it's the default port, but your db might use another one, you can use mysqli if you want. I think pdo is easier to use and supports more databases than only mysql, but if you are sure to always use mysql and mysqli suits you its fine. And to clarify there is no such thing as a phpmyadmin db, the db is mysql, and phpmyadmin is just an admin panel to connect to it.